# Pros and cons of using MessageFormat

Tags: java, string

Is it advisable to use `java.text.MessageFormat` to do operations on Strings? Or any alternative?

Comment: Advisable by what measure? What is your use case?

Comment: It's useful in so far as it formats messages. For example you can format numbers (eg add leading zeros etc). The only alternatives I know are other libraries or code ou write yourself. MessagFormat is pretty powerful though so I would investigate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, [MessageFormats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html) are particularly useful when you need to define them externally, e.g. via a Resource.

You can have different MessageFormats for different languages and they can present your fields in a different order suitable to the language.

For the simplest of needs I would use String `+` e.g.

```
out.println("Message: " + message+", count: "+ count);
```

For more complex formatting needs I would use String format.

```
put.printf("Percent %6.2f%%, bytes: %,d%n", percent, byteCount);
```

Where you need to be able to configure your message format, I believe MessageFormat is likely to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The advantages of using MessageFormat are

- The message format will come from resources, and the arguments will
  be dynamically set at runtime.
- The message format API is a great way to abstract the general
  structure of a message from the actual content.
- MessageFormat takes a set of objects, formats them, then inserts the
  formatted strings into the pattern at the appropriate places

The disadventages of using MessageFormat is

- The rules for using quotes within message format patterns
  unfortunately have shown to be somewhat confusing.